# sub heardword (byval as skypecall) in a BUTTON?

Tags: vb.net, button, pass-by-value

I'm trying to interface with Skype and I have an example code

```
Imports HSPI_SKYPE

Sub HEARDWORD(ByVal c as SkypeCall)
    c.speaktextwait("you said" & c.lastwordRecognized)
End Sub
```

but I want it inside a button

```
Private Sub button20_click(sender as Object. e as EventArgs) Handles29.click
    Dim c as SkypeCall
    c.speaktextwait("you said" & c.lastwordRecognized)
End Sub
```

This doesn't work. How do i get Skype to repeat the last heard word when I press the button?

Comment: why cant you just invoke `HEARDWORD` from whereever?  Please read [Ask], the [FAQ] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: when i tried to do it my way. It states variable C is used before it has been assigned a value. And the error says "an unhandled exception has occurred.   BUT i can call hearword from the button, after creating a private sub like in the example problem. but it was has not specified parameter 'c'

Comment: idk what to put inside "heardword(???)"

Comment: Nor do I, but you need an instance of that `SkypeCall` class. Read the documentation for whatever API it is you're using, it must contain some info.